# Using Viewbag to View Search Query on Screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, view

I have this view where a user searches for a particular Knowledgebase article and at the top of the view of the results I would like to show the user what their search criteria is. So I am using viewbag but it is coming up blank.

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult UserSearchKnowledgebase(SearchKnowledgebase searchKnowledgebase)
        {


            var model = db.Knowledgebases.AsQueryable();
            if (searchKnowledgebase.CreatedById != Guid.Empty)
            {
                model = model.Where(k => k.CreatedById == searchKnowledgebase.CreatedById);
                ViewBag.Createdby = searchKnowledgebase.CreatedBy.FullName;
            }
            if (searchKnowledgebase.CategoryId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                model = model.Where(k => k.CategoryId == searchKnowledgebase.CategoryId);
                ViewBag.Category = searchKnowledgebase.Category.CategoryName;
            }
            model = model.OrderBy(k => k.CreatedDate);
            var result = model.ToList();

            return View("UserKnowledgebaseList", result);

        }
```

and here is my view code:

```
<h3>Knowledgebase: Category: @ViewBag.Category      Created by: @ViewBag.Createdby</h3>
```

Here is my ViewModel code:

```
namespace HelpDesk.WebUI.ViewModel
{
    public class SearchKnowledgebase
    {

        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Created By")]
        public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }

        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public Guid TypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Type { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I thought I figured it out and tried this but still am getting nothing:

```
ViewBag.Category = db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryId == searchKnowledgebase.CategoryId).First().CategoryName;
```

Comment: blank means compete blank h3??

Comment: Ehsan, No just for the viewbag results.  So the word Category shows up but @viewbag.Category will not show up.

Comment: Just a thought, but are you sure that the ViewBag.Createdby and .Category values are single items ("string", etc)? It seems like you could be setting the ViewBag values to type IQueryable or something.

Comment: SearchKnowledgebase is only a viewmodel where the user choses what to search for.  So the returned values should be single value strings. But now that you said that - they technically return the Ids for those fields.  So I will need to turn them into the values. Let me try that.

Comment: Can you update you question with the searchKnowledgebase.Category structure?

Comment: @theLaw I updated my original post with also another try that I had.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't leave comments so I have to post an answer...Are you sure that CreatedByID and CategoryID have values? Maybe it skips over that block of code completely? If you can see if you can put a breakpoint on that particular line

Comment: Yes, because the search portion already works based on those fields.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on that line and see if the code runs? You should be able to see what the value is

Comment: Code, you are correct.  Odd it is coming up as null.  Now I am confused because it was working prior.

Comment: Try hardcoding some test values into the 2 ViewBags at the start of the controller (meaning take the ViewBag variables out of the if statements an put at the top of the controller).....ViewBag.Createdby = "My Name" , ViewBag.Category = "Cat"